# How to connect Point in Time api with opensearch using Java client for performRequest()

Tags: java, opensearch, java-client, point-in-time

I have to call Point in Time
like

```
/<target_indexes>/_search/point_in_time?keep_alive=1h&routing=&expand_wildcards=&preference=
```

using java client API of OpenSearch

I have tried to create the client using the java client API.
Though after that I want to create request object but there is no help available for this.

```
 String endPoint = "/movie-index/_search/point_in_time";
 Request request = new Request("POST", endPoint);
 request.addParameter("keep_alive",1h);
Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
```

the above code I was used in java rest high level client..

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide the code you currently have to make the request?

Comment: I have added code snippet in the question

Comment: Adding the error message, stacktrace and code for creation of the client to the question would be helpful.